# Encryption using Openssl EVP library and decryption using openssl enc terminal command fails

Tags: c, security, encryption, openssl

I am trying to encrypt a string using OpenSSL EVP library, and decrypt subsequently using the openssl command from a linux terminal.
OpenSSL command for decryption:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -base64 -salt -d -md md5 -k <passphrase> -in encrypt.txt -out plain.txt
```

Encryption code:

```
int CAES::encrypt(const char* msg, unsigned char** encrypted_message, const size_t msg_len, const unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, const unsigned char* salt) 
{
    //this buffer will hold the salt and the cipher
    const int buffer_len ( CAES::salt_info_size + std::max((int)(msg_len * 2), EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH) );
    unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[buffer_len];
    //this will be a pointer to the cipher only
    unsigned char* cipher = CAES::salt_info_size + buffer;
    size_t bytes_encrypted(0);
    bool encryption_error(true);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *cipher_ctx( create_cipher_ctx(encryption, key, iv) );
    (void) EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(cipher_ctx, EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
        size_t cipher_len(0);
    int temp_len(0);
    if( EVP_EncryptUpdate(cipher_ctx, cipher, &temp_len, (unsigned char *)msg, strlen(msg)) )
    {
        cipher_len = temp_len;
        if( EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(cipher_ctx, cipher + temp_len, &temp_len) )
        {
            cipher_len += temp_len;
        }
        cipher[cipher_len] = '\0';
        encryption_error = false;
        bytes_encrypted = cipher_len;
    }
    memcpy(buffer + 0 , CAES::salt_tag, CAES::salt_tag_size);
    memcpy(buffer + CAES::salt_tag_size, salt, CAES::salt_size);
    memcpy(*encrypted_message, buffer, CAES::salt_info_size + bytes_encrypted);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(cipher_ctx);
    delete[] buffer;
    return CAES::salt_info_size + bytes_encrypted;
}
```

Code to encode the encrypted string from above to base64:

```
int CBase64::encode(const unsigned char* msg, const size_t msg_len, char** b64_msg) {
  size_t bytes_encoded = 0;
  bytes_encoded = EVP_EncodeBlock((unsigned char *) *b64_msg, msg, msg_len);
  return bytes_encoded;
}
```

Key and IV derivation

```
void CAES::init_key_iv(const std::string& pass, const unsigned char* salt, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv )
{
  const unsigned char * pass_key = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( pass.c_str() );
  const size_t pass_key_len ( pass.size() );
  EVP_BytesToKey(CAES::cipher_type, CAES::msg_digest_type, salt, pass_key, pass_key_len, 1, key, iv);
}
```

The following are the key sizes and salt derivation:

```
unsigned char salt[8] = {};
unsigned char key[32] = {};
unsigned char iv_enc[16] = {};
RAND_bytes(salt, 8);
```

Case 1:

```
const char* password = "@N";
const char* msg = "neo4j";
```

On trying to decrypt I get the following:

```
bad decrypt
140589946300064:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
```

Case 2:

```
const char* password = "eemnsis";
const char* msg = "This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.This is long message, repeating 10 times.";
```

On trying to decrypt I get the following:

```
error reading input file
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the Base64-encoding.

In the `openssl` statement for decryption, the `-base64` option is used without the `-A` option. Therefore, a formatted Base64-string is expected, i.e. after each 64 byte and at the end there are line breaks, see [`-A`-Option](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-enc.html).

However, the current `encode` function does *not* do this, but writes the entire Base64-string in a *single* line.

The problem can be solved by

- either adding the `-A` option to the `openssl` statement for decryption: `-base64 -A`
- or modifying the `encode` method to include line breaks, e.g. with [`EVP_EncodeUpdate`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_EncodeUpdate.html) etc.):

  ```
  int CBase64::encode(const unsigned char* msg, const size_t msg_len, char** b64_msg) {
      int len, total = 0;
      EVP_ENCODE_CTX *ectx = EVP_ENCODE_CTX_new();
      EVP_EncodeInit(ectx);
      EVP_EncodeUpdate(ectx, (unsigned char *)*b64_msg, &len, msg, msg_len);
      total += len;
      EVP_EncodeFinal(ectx, (unsigned char *)*b64_msg + len, &len);
      total += len;
      EVP_ENCODE_CTX_free(ectx);
      return total;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
```EVP_ENCODE_CTX_new``` and ```EVP_ENCODE_CTX_free``` are not available to me.

Comment: As a reminder: You can also use the `-A`-option when decrypting with `openssl`!
Otherwise, you will need to find a Base64 encoding compatible with your environment that takes line breaks into account. It's hard to recommend anything because I don't know your environment, but there are a number of implementations on the Internet, e.g. https://gist.github.com/barrysteyn/7308212. Here the flag `BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL` is set in the `Base64Encode` function to write the Base64 string in one line. Possibly this method can be adapted to take line breaks into account (I haven't tried it though).